# How to captalize and title a string

Tags: c++, string

If I was given a string, I need to either **capitalize** or **title** the string. For example:

Comment: Isn't your first loop overriding Ret every iteration. Think it needs to be Ret += tolower(c)

Comment: You also probably don't need the first loop you can do something directly like: Ret = str; transform(Ret.begin(), Ret.end(), Ret.begin(), ::tolower);

Comment: Your 2nd loop also doesn't have a termination condition? Probably for(int i = 0; i < Ret.size(); i++)....

Comment: what about now, I edited it

Comment: What's not working?  In `Title` function, you are accessing `Ret[i-1]` and starting the loop from `0`. You should start from `i=1;`

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code. Here is the modified version of your code that works fine. Here:

```
std::string Capitalize(const std::string &str) {
std::string Ret;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    char c = str[i];
    if (i == 0){
        Ret += toupper(c);
    }
    else if (i != 0){
        Ret += (tolower(c));
    }
}
return Ret;}
```

Condition in for loop needs to be str.length() not Ret.length() and here :

```
std::string Title(const std::string &str) {
std::string Ret;
int i=0;
for (int i=0;i<str.size();i++) {
    if(!(i==0 && str[i]==' '))
        Ret += tolower(str[i]);
}

int size = Ret.length();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i==0  || Ret[i - 1] == ' ')
    {
        Ret[i] = toupper(Ret[i]);
    }
}
return Ret;}
```

Check if i is 0 to prevent out of range access to string.

Comment: How it will process `Title(" HELLO WORLD")`. how will it remove first 'space' character?

Answer (score 0):

Use a stringstream to first split all words, so that you can do this easily with a vector. This is an implementation of the `Title` function:

```
 std::string Title(const std::string &str) {
     std::vector<string>words;
     words.clear();
     std::string res = str, std::ans = "";
     // It's better to pass the string AFTER you convert it all lowercase. Or you can only work with the capitalized characters:
     for(int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i){
         if(res[i] >= 'A' && res[i] <= 'Z'){
             res[i] = tolower(res[i]);
         }
     }

     istringstream ss(res); // We push the modified string into a stringstream.

     do{
        res = "";
        ss >> res;
        words.push_back(res); // We split the string at " " and push each word in the vector.
     } while(ss)


     for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i){
           res = words[i];
           res[0] = toUpper(res[0]); // For each word, we capitalize it
           ans += res; // We add the word to our return string.
           if(i < words.size() - 1){
               ans += " "; // If this is not the last word, add a space 
           }
     }
     return ans;
 }
```

As for the capitalization, you can do something like this:

```
std::string Capitalize(const std::string &&str){

    std::string res = str;
    res[0] = toupper(res[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < res.size(); ++i){
        if(res[i] >= 'A' && res[i] <= 'Z'){
            res[i] = tolower(res[i]); // converting if only an uppercase character.
        }
    }
    return res; // If you pass a reference, the original will be modified so no return required.
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to modify the str, i would need to create another string and append to that and then return that one

Comment: You can declare `std::string Ret` as you did earlier and assign that `str` to it

Comment: I have updated the answer to work with a new string

Comment: @shay It is encouraged to work this way with the vector. Manosh, Damn I was about to post the answer :D:D

Comment: @RC0993 :D :D My favorite way of handling these things